# Content not being added to pdf page

Tags: java, pdf, arraylist, collections, pdfbox

I wrote this program to read String values from `ArrayList` and write them to pdf file using pdfbox.
Except for the string **List of Strings** no other strings are not being added.Here's the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;

public class pdfBoxTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
        r.add("Jack and ");r.add("Jill ");r.add("Went up");r.add(" the hill");
        try{
            PDDocument file = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            file.addPage(page);

                PDPageContentStream data = new PDPageContentStream(file, page);
                data.beginText();
                data.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 20);
                float x=220,y=750;
                data.newLineAtOffset(x, y);
                data.showText("List of Strings");
                for(int i=0;i<r.size();i++){                    
                    String line=r.get(i);
                    System.out.println(line);
                    data.newLineAtOffset(x, y);
                    data.showText(line);
                    y+=100;
                }

                data.close();
                file.save("res.pdf");
                file.close();
        }
         catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();   }

      }

    }
```

Comment: You need to provide more information - this will help you formulate a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you introduce this line:

```
data.beginText();
```

You start creating a text object in PDF.

However, you also need this line:

```
data.endText();
```

This completes the text object. You don't have a complete text object which can lead to strange results.

Furthermore, you don't seem to be aware about the coordinate system in PDF. See the following FAQ entries:

- [How should I interpret the coordinates of a rectangle in PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-should-i-interpret-coordinates-rectangle-pdf)
- [Where is the origin (x,y) of a PDF page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/where-origin-xy-pdf-page)

Change this line:

```
y+=100;
```

To this:

```
y-=100;
```

You started with `float x=220,y=750;` I don't know the default page size in PdfBox, but let's assume it's an A4 page. In that case, the pages measures 595 (width) by 842 (height) user units, and `float x=220,y=750;` is more or less in the middle (horizontally) and near the top (vertically).

When you add 100 to `y`, you end up with `y = 850`, which means that you're getting out of the visible area of the page (because 850 is higher than 842). You are adding the text, and the text is in the content stream you are creating, but the text isn't visible, because it's outside the `/MediaBox` of the page.

Finally: the `newLineAtOffset()` method doesn't move the content to the coordinates you define, but starts a new line and uses the parameters as *offset from the current position.* So even if you change `y` the way I explained, you are moving the content to a position that is totally different form the position at the `(x, y)` coordinate.

**Bottom line:** PdfBox requires that you know PDF syntax. If you don't know PDF syntax (which is clear from your question), you should consider using iText. (Disclaimer: I am the CTO of iText Group.)

#### The OP's mistake in detail (edit by mkl)

In contrast to what the OP desired, the method call `data.newLineAtOffset(x, y)` does **not** accept **absolute coordinates** but **instead** expects **coordinates relative to the former line start**:

```
/**
 * The Td operator.
 * Move to the start of the next line, offset from the start of the current line by (tx, ty).
 *
 * @param tx The x translation.
 * @param ty The y translation.
 * @throws IOException If there is an error writing to the stream.
 * @throws IllegalStateException If the method was not allowed to be called at this time.
 */
public void newLineAtOffset(float tx, float ty) throws IOException
```

Thus, considering the OP's attempt to use a **y** coordinate change of 100 downwards, the call of that method in the loop should be

```
data.newLineAtOffset(0, -100);
```

Comment: added it,but still not working.only the first string is added.rest is ignored

Comment: No, the rest is not ignored. It's just not visible! See the update of my question.

Comment: @Bruno - actually `newLineAtOffset` corresponds to **Td**. Thus,  the arguments used by the OP in the loop are even more wrong than you thought.

Comment: @mkl I'm not that proficient in PdfBox, feel free to correct my answer.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Started using itext for pdf files.Much more easier to work with

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I added it as an appendix.